# Can't send output to label in VB

Tags: vb.net, conditional-statements, arithmetic-expressions

The piece of code I have makes it so that when the radio button is checked then the whole total is multiplied by 2. The equation is 500 times 2, and the 1000 is being stored but I can't display it somehow.

Code:

```
    If radMeter.Checked Then
        intTotal = CInt(intMeter.ToString("C"))

    ElseIf radZone.Checked Then
        intTotal = CInt(intParking.ToString("C"))

    ElseIf radBlocking.Checked Then
        intTotal = CInt(intDriveway.ToString("C"))

    ElseIf radHandicap.Checked Then
        intTotal = CInt(intHandicap.ToString("C"))

        If radRepeat.Checked Then
            lblTotal.Text = CStr(2 * CDbl(intTotal.ToString("C")))
        End If

    End If

    'Output
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal.ToString("C")
```

Specifically at line 13 "radRepeat"

Comment: `CDbl(intTotal.ToString("C"))` ... you take an integer, convert it to string and then parse it again to double. Why do you do that? That does not make sense.

Comment: How exactly is this failing?  When you step through this in a debugger, where does it go wrong?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  Setting the value of `lblTotal.Text` will set the text of that label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review your code carefully - you are actually writing TWICE to the label (causing your changes to be overwritten, and never saved in your intTotal variable):

```
    If radRepeat.Checked Then
       **lblTotal.Text** = CStr(2 * CDbl(intTotal.ToString("C")))
    End If

End If

'Output
**lblTotal.Text** = intTotal.ToString("C")
```

You should replace:

```
lblTotal.Text = CStr(2 * CDbl(intTotal.ToString("C")))
```

With

```
intTotal = (2 * intTotal)
```

And then let your last statement write to the label as normal.

If you are trying to NOT change the value in intTotal, but still display the doubled amount in a label, then you should move your label writing into your If... Else... block

Answer (score 3):

In your last line:

```
'Output
lblTotal.Text = intTotal.ToString("C")
```

You overwrite lblTotal with the *current* value of intTotal, which you did *not* multiply by 2 (i.e., you overwrite what you did in line 13).

The easiest way to fix that is to replace

```
lblTotal.Text = CStr(2 * CDbl(intTotal.ToString("C")))
```

with

```
intTotal = 2 * intTotal
```

Answer (score 2):

What you may want to try to do, to see if there really is a bug with the code or just a simple logic error is insert a few breaks after each block of code.

What I could possibly see is that that when you have the radio button handicap checked, and additionally have the radio button repeat checked, the code will calculate the value * 2, but after the if then statement closes it will write again to the text field of of the lblTotal, making it seem as though it did not calculate.

I assume of course that you have at least two groups allowing more than one radio button to be checked at a time.

I would suggest the following fix:

```
If radRepeat.Checked Then
        intTotal = CStr(2 * CDbl(intTotal.ToString("C")))
End If
```

That way, your output will work for all the previous if/then statements.

Edit:
I realize that this essentially was covered by the comment above me, and cleaned up a bit.

If it were me I would have setup things a bit differently and spare my keystrokes, in the sense that if you are just calculating using integers, wait until the output line to do any converting to string, double, or whatever the case may be.

That would look something like this:

```
    If radMeter.Checked Then
    intTotal = intMeter

ElseIf radZone.Checked Then
    intTotal = intParking

ElseIf radBlocking.Checked Then
    intTotal = intDriveway

ElseIf radHandicap.Checked Then
    intTotal = intHandicap

    If radRepeat.Checked Then
        intTotal = (2 * intTotal)
    End If

End If

'Output
lblTotal.Text = intTotal.ToString("C")
```

Of course, this is given that these int(Variables) were properly introduced.